# Implementing confirmation view and template in django

Tags: django

I have two views one that accepts inputs and the other for confirmation and execution of an action. My problem is how to confirm the inputs from another view and template.

This is similar when you delete a record. That you should confirm from the user his actions.

Here is the input view. PreprocessinputationView:

```
def PreprocessInputationView(request, **kwargs):
    proj_pk = kwargs.get('pk')
    project = Project.objects.get(id=proj_pk)  
    df      = pd.read_csv(project.base_file)
    n_cols  = df.keys

    context            = {}
    context['df']      = df
    context['n_cols']  = n_cols
    context['project'] = project

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # try:       
        checked_value   = request.POST.getlist(u'predictors')
        method = ''.join(request.POST.getlist(u'method'))
        if checked_value and method:
            context['checked_value'] = checked_value
            context['method'] = method

            return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/confirm_inputation.html', context)

    return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/preprocess_inputation.html', context)
```

The confirmation view goes here. ConfirmInputationView:

```
def ConfirmInputationView(request, context):
    print('method:', context['method'])
    project = context['project']  
    df      = pd.read_csv(project.base_file)
    n_cols  = df.keys

    filename = project.base_file.name
    tmp = filename.split('/')
    filename = str(tmp[1:])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # try:       
        checked_value = context['checked_value']
        method        = context['method']

        if checked_value and (method=='mean'):
            df[checked_value].fillna(df[checked_value].mean())

            # df.drop(columns=checked_values, inplace=True)
            new_df            = df.to_csv(index=False)

            updated_file      = ContentFile(new_df)
            updated_file.name = filename 

            project.base_file = updated_file
            project.save()

            str_checked_value = ', '.join(checked_value)
            context['str_checked_value'] = str_checked_value
            if str_checked_value:       
                messages.success(request, f'Inputation to column(s) {str_checked_value} successful!')         

    return render(request, 'projects/preprocess/preprocess_inputation.html', context)
```

The confirmation template. Confirm_inputation.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_heading %}
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Delete Project</h1>
</div>
{% endblock page_heading %}

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron col-xl-8 col-md-6 mb-1"">
    <form method=" POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class='form-group'>
            <p>

                You have chosen <strong>{{ method }}</strong> as an inputation method?

                Are you sure you want to proceed?
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger float-sm-right mr-1" type="submit">Yes, Delete</button>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary float-sm-right mr-1" href="{% url 'project-detail' project.id %}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The data from the `PreprocessImputationView` should be passed to `ConfirmImputationView` for confirmation and processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question or rather problem. So I'll summarize what I understood. Please clarify more, if this doesn't fit your problem.

You have view A (PreprocessInputationView), which shows the user some values/forms and allows some POST action to A.
If view A receives a POST request you check the form input and render template B of view B.

Your rendered template B offers two options to the user: Accept, which triggers POST to view B or decline, which links to some details view.

I think what you're missing is, that `context` in `render` is "lost" after rendering. The moment the user sees the finished html page that variable is no longer relevant and inaccessible.

A way to provide the necessary 'method' information to your B view would be to add a form field to your B template, which holds some sort of key for B view to determine on POST what to do. Like a hidden input field with a number. Each number would predetermined stand for a method.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Can I create a form without a model in this case?

Comment: Yes that would work. This way your already existent fieldset with the message about the method could be part of it too and you could reduce your form code in the template.